# URL to change sharepoint list status

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-list

I'm creating a sharepoint list with different issues from a team to attend.
When i go inside, i can change the status manually

https://BlaBlaBla.com/Lists/BlaBlaBla/EditForm.aspx?ID=10

I would like to create an URL that when clicked, it changes the status of that sharepoint item to status=completed.
I've got the ID of that list element available, so i would like to know if there is any argument i can add to this link to make it automatic.

Any idea to help me out?
thanks in advance!